# Resolve error that says javafx.fxml does not exist

Tags: java, javafx

I am using `Java 13`. Can someone help me with how to add `java.fxml` file? Is it possible with this SDK?

Comment: Start here: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Comment: This really depends on where you place the fxml file and how you package/run the program.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create from your IDE (Intellij for example) an JavaFX project and the fxml file will be added.